# Get value from associative array using the key name

Tags: php, associative-array

I have an array of objects and I would like to access the values by the keys.

```
    <?php

    $name = [
                [
                    'firstname'  => 'John',
                    'lastname'   => 'Doe',
                    'middlename' => 'Bray'
                ],
                [
                    'firstname'  => 'John2',
                    'lastname'   => 'Doe2',
                    'middlename' => 'Bray2'
                ]           
    ];

    $count = count($name);
    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
        $cell = $name[$i];
        echo $cell->lastname;
        echo $cell->middlename;
    }   
?>
```

I thought that the 2 last lines would do but I get an error!
What do I need to do o make  it work?

Regards,
Elio Fernandes

Comment: I didnt understand what you asked and what you need

Comment: $cell['lastname'] instead of  $cell->lastname;

Comment: Also look up using the php function foreach.

Comment: Welcome aboard, Elio. I see that you already got your answer. Just to help you in future, you said " I get an error!" - it will help if you actually post the error, so that we don't have to guess :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$cell` is an associative array, not an object. The syntax for accessing elements in an associative array is `$arr['key']`. The syntax for accessing properties of objects is `$obj->prop`.

So, use it like this:

```
echo $cell['lastname'];
echo $cell['middlename'];
```

Comment: Thanks to all for your answers and suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
echo $cell->lastname;
echo $cell->middlename;
```

with

```
echo $cell['lastname'];
echo $cell['middlename'];
```

Answer (score 2):

change

```
echo $cell->lastname;
```

to

```
echo $cell['lastname'];
```

You are playing with an array not an object.

Moreover, you can use `foreach` loop instead of `for` as you won't have to get count and loop till count.

```
 foreach($name as $cell){...
```